# working with python binding for Zombie.js gives error while creating Browser object

Tags: python-2.7, zombie.js

```
>>> from zombie import Browser
>>> b=Browser()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    b=Browser()
  File "/Users/gaurav/Documents/python-zombie/zombie/browser.py", line 24, in __init__
    server = ZombieProxyServer()
  File "/Users/gaurav/Documents/python-zombie/zombie/proxy/server.py", line 56, in ZombieProxyServer
    instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gaurav/Documents/python-zombie/zombie/proxy/server.py", line 107, in __init__
    "The proxy server has not replied within 3 seconds."
RuntimeError: The proxy server has not replied within 3 seconds.
```

Any idea where am i going wrong?

Comment: Does Zombie.js work in the first place?

Comment: @Blender how do we verify that?